# What is m2repository folder in local android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-sdk-2.3

I was trying to look for a list of version for android support library, and finally i found **m2repository** and support folders in android folder. What is that?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `m2repository` folder is a Maven repository which contains all the support libraries as AAR archives. This is what Gradle uses when you tell it that your project depends on these libraries.

The `support` folder contains the same libraries, except they are structured as Android library projects with a library JAR and resources in the corresponding folders. You only need the `support` folder if you use the old Ant-based build system.

Comment: Does that happen to mean that I have to add `mavenLocal()` to my `build.gradle` file to access the imports of `android.support.*`?